# Uneven content automatically centering in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using a theme I've built myself but am having trouble aligning uneven posts to the left as in the example below:

http://savvyretiree.wpengine.com/category/online-income-opportunities/

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `justify-content: space-between;` on `section`?

Comment: That's done it, thanks for the prompt solution :)

Comment: Let's vote me LOL!

Comment: Haha, I have but they won't register it :/

Comment: Aaaarg true try to accept the answer below!

Answer (score 0):

```
section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Regards Tom

Answer (score 0):

Try `justify-content: space-between;` on `section`.